# Border Style-Tigger doesn't accept background setter

Tags: wpf

I've got a small problem, which can be solved for now differently, but I would like to do it via the Style.Trigger of the Border.

My current style for the border looks like this:

```
    <Style x:Key="style_BorderStatus" TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="75"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#ccc"/>
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#9f9"/>
                <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

My Border looks like this:

```
<Border Grid.Column="0" Margin="2 2 1 2" Style="{StaticResource style_BorderStatus}">
    <TextBlock x:Name="txtStatusKind" Foreground="#999" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="24"/>
</Border>
```

This works fine so far, even the cursor changes after I set the border to IsEnabled=true.
This means that the trigger style basically works already.
But why is the background setter not affected?

Comment: You may have explicitly set the Background of the Border where this Style is applied, which would take higher precedence than the values from the Style Setters.

Comment: I've tried your code, it is working fine!

Comment: @Clemens No I didn't. I took the XAML into my post, there's no background property set.

Comment: This is a little bit surprising to me, that my code runs for you, @Muhammad Sulaiman. For me there is furthermore only the cursor changing.

Comment: How exactly are you setting the IsEnabled property of an unnamed Border?

Comment: I've a stack panel with multiple borders like that as childs. To avoid having to give each one a name, I iterate over the children and set the property. In a context model I have a property that indicates the current border what references the current action, so that I can select each border for its own by using the index of the collection. I'm not a friend of giving every element a name. Makes it more scalable I think.

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake, thanks to @Clemens' hint. I've an initialization method in which I set the color values initially, this also has a higher priority than the styles.

It works now, thanks @all